# Unsure as to why my class function isn't working

Tags: php

I am in the middle of making a script at the moment and I have a PHP file called `ban.php` and the idea is to ban IPs. I have a class called `Banning` which is located inside `inc/class.Banning.inc.php`. As there is the ability to ban both single IP addresses and IP ranges I decided to have a `$_GET` request. For example: `ban.php?type=single` would load the form for a single IP address and `ban.php?type=range` would load the form for IP ranges.

This is the Banning class:

```
/**
* BANNING CLASS
*/
class Banning {
    /**
     * VARIABLES
     */
    private $_Gtype;
    private $_G_Result;

    /**
     * Constructor, set variables to ban.php $_GET
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->_Gtype = isset($_GET['type']) ? $_GET['type'] : null;
    }

    /**
     * GET THE BANNING TYPE FROM $_GET IN BAN.PHP
     */
    public function getType() {
        // Get the type of banning form from $_GET
        if ($this->_Gtype == 'single') {
            $this->_G_Result == 'single';
        } else if ($this->_Gtype == 'range') {
            $this->_G_Result == 'range';
        }
        // Return the value
        return $this->_G_Result;
    }
}
```

Then In my `ban.php` file I have the following:

```
require_once('inc/class.Banning.inc.php');
define('BAN_IP', true); // define the ban constant

/**
 * DETERMINE WHICH FORM TO DISPLAY REGARDING $_GET
 * Making use of the getType() function in Banning Class.
 */

$getType = new Banning();

if ($getType->getType() == 'single') {
require_once('html/ban.single.php');
}

?>
<style type="text/css">
    <?php require_once('css/css.css'); ?>
 </style>
```

I have errors all turned on in my `httpd.conf` file and I am running this on my mac (MAMP).
When I run the page `ban.php?type=single` I am left with a blank page. Is there anything wrong with what I have done?

Comment: Unsure, but shouldn't `ban.php?type=single` be `ban.php?_Gtype=single` or `ban.php?Gtype=single`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- The Gtype variable is assigned to the $_GET['type'] in the constructor.

Comment: See the answer below, I just saw this `$this->_G_Result == 'single';` you're not assigning, but comparing. Do `$this->_G_Result = 'single';` and do the same for the other.

Comment: I tested your code with my comment above and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assign values with double equal-signes.

```
if ($this->_Gtype == 'single') {
    $this->_G_Result == 'single';
} else if ($this->_Gtype == 'range') {
    $this->_G_Result == 'range';
}
```

Should be

```
if ($this->_Gtype == 'single') {
    $this->_G_Result = 'single';
} else if ($this->_Gtype == 'range') {
    $this->_G_Result = 'range';
}
```

Btw, you never check is the value of `_Gtype` is null or not. This might cause unintended behaviour.

Comment: *"Btw, you never check is the value of _Gtype is null or not."* - I believe OP is, in using a ternary operator `isset($_GET['type']) ? $_GET['type'] : null`

Comment: I can't believe I keep doing that, I've been at my computer for hours so I'm getting a bit sloppy. Thank you :)